# UnknownHostException: name or service not known

Tags: java, exception, host, okhttp

I'm attempting to return some data from an API using OkHttpClient in com.squareup.okhttp. I've run into a few errors that i have eventually been able to overcome but i can't get past this host exception error and nothing on here seems to be specific enough to my case to be able to solve.

Below is the code i have attempted along with the output with it, if anyone has any idea how to overcome the error i would appreciate it.

**CODE**

```
public void connect() {         
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    com.squareup.okhttp.Request request = new com.squareup.okhttp.Request.Builder()
    .url("https://socialweb-analytics.lcloud.com/api/public/reports/jobs?companyKey=ato")
    .get()
    .addHeader("authorization", "Basic c2RidXNpbmVzc2FuYWx5dGljc0BhdG8uZ292LmF1OkFuYWx5dGljezEh")
    .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
    .addHeader("postman-token", "65ef5553-77b5-053f-9c01-4fdf76bdc92f")
    .build();

    System.out.println(request.toString());

    try {
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        System.out.println(response);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Request{method=GET, url=https://socialweb-analytics.lcloud.com/api/public/reports/jobs?companyKey=ato, tag=null}
java.net.UnknownHostException: socialweb-analytics.lcloud.com: Name or service not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:922)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1314)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1267)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1183)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1119)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:187)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:156)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:98)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:344)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:327)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:245)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:267)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:224)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:195)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:79)
    at technical_services.persistence.lithium.LithiumDataStore.connect1(LithiumDataStore.java:127)
    at application.lithium_etl.LithiumTestController.main(LithiumTestController.java:24)
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem as you have. Were you able to arrive at a solution?? @Jordan Macey-Smith ?

Answer (score 34):

For error like "java.net.UnknownHostException: [hostname]"

The reason is your hostname is not in /etc/hosts, The solution is simple:

```
sudo vim /etc/hosts
```

change the line looks like:

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
```

to:

```
127.0.0.1  [hostname] localhost
```

Save and exit. If the problem still exist, may be you need to restart or run :

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 down&&sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

Hope it can help you!

Comment: can you please tell based on the field , `ip-address`, `hostname.domain.org` `hostname`

Answer (score 6):

Expanding on zhenbo xu's great answer this is what I did to automate things with `sed` in EC2.

`sudo sed -i -e '/127.0.0.1/ s/\(localhost\)/'$(hostname)' \1/' /etc/hosts`

Note that to allow variable expansion the single quotes end and restart around the subshell call.

`hostname` is an executable on some Linux systems (but maybe not all, so you can use an environment variable instead,or remove the quotes around the subshell and use static string).

The `\1` is `sed` magic, it puts the "captured" search string (s/search/replacement/) in the escaped parentheses back into the replacement string.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not posted your code that how your `connect()` called, so please refer to my following working code

```
    private class StringRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("https://socialweb-analytics.lcloud.com/api/public/reports/jobs?companyKey=ato")
                    .addHeader("authorization", "Basic c2RidXNpbmVzc2FuYWx5dGljc0BhdG8uZ292LmF1OkFuYWx5dGljezEh")
                    .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
                    .addHeader("postman-token", "65ef5553-77b5-053f-9c01-4fdf76bdc92f")
                    .build();
            try {
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                return response.body().string();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
```

Then inside onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    new StringRequest().execute();
}
```

My app run and got the following result (perhaps because of expired/invalid token):

```
I/System.out: {"code":500,"message":"There was an error processing your request. It has been logged (ID a2f28b587b2f9dcc)."}
```

P/S: make sure you have set `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` inside `AndroidManifest.xml` file