# Logging exception stacktrace with custom rollingFileAppender and custom JsonLayout

Tags: java, log4j, logback, slf4j

I have written a custom logger with its own rolling file appender. I am logging an exception using one of the log messages (e.g., info(), debug(), etc.), I am excepting that it would print the entire stacktrace of the exception, but it is printing only the message.

```
public class Logger {

    private static ConcurrentHashMap<String, Logger> loggerMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Logger>();
    private static ConcurrentHashMap<String, FileAppender> appenderMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, FileAppender>();
    private static LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();

    public static org.slf4j.Logger getLoggerWithRollingFileAppender(String appenderName,
                                                              String loggerName,
                                                              Level logLevel) {

        RollingFileAppender rollingFileAppender;

        // Check if the appender is already created.
        if (! appenderMap.containsKey(appenderName)) {
            LayoutWrappingEncoder jsonEncoder = new LayoutWrappingEncoder();
            JsonFormatter jsonFormatter = new JacksonJsonFormatter();
            ((JacksonJsonFormatter) jsonFormatter).setPrettyPrint(false);
            JsonLayout jsonLayout = new JsonLayout();
            jsonLayout.setJsonFormatter(jsonFormatter);
            jsonLayout.setTimestampFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
            jsonLayout.setContext(loggerContext);
            jsonLayout.setAppendLineSeparator(true);
            jsonLayout.setIncludeException(true);
            jsonLayout.setIncludeMDC(true);
            jsonEncoder.setLayout(jsonLayout);
            jsonEncoder.setContext(loggerContext);
            jsonEncoder.start();

            rollingFileAppender = new RollingFileAppender();
            rollingFileAppender.setContext(loggerContext);
            rollingFileAppender.setName(appenderName);
            rollingFileAppender.setEncoder(jsonEncoder);
            rollingFileAppender.setAppend(true);

            SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy sizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy =
                    new SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy();
            sizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy.setContext(loggerContext);
            sizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy.setParent(rollingFileAppender);
            sizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy.setFileNamePattern(logBaseDir +
                    File.separator +
                    appenderName + "-" +
                    applnName + "-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log");
            sizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy.setMaxHistory(maxLogHistory);
            sizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy.setMaxFileSize(FileSize.valueOf(maxLogFileSize));
            sizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy.setTotalSizeCap(FileSize.valueOf(totalLogSizeCap));
            sizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy.start();
            rollingFileAppender.setRollingPolicy(sizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy);
            rollingFileAppender.start();
            appenderMap.put(appenderName, rollingFileAppender);
        } else {
            rollingFileAppender = (RollingFileAppender) appenderMap.get(appenderName);
        }

        // Return the logger
        org.slf4j.Logger slf4jLogger = getLogger(loggerName);
        Logger logger = (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) slf4jLogger;
        logger.setAdditive(false);
        logger.setLevel(logLevel);
        logger.addAppender(rollingFileAppender);
        return slf4jLogger;
    } 
}

@Test
void testExceptionWithLoggerWithRollingFileAppender() {

    org.slf4j.Logger slf4jLogger = Logger.getLoggerWithRollingFileAppender
            ("testAppender",
             "com.test7",
             Level.DEBUG);
    try {
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("dummyfile.txt");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        slf4jLogger.info("Exception is", e);
    }
    Logger logger = (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) slf4jLogger;
    logger.debug("This is a log message");
    try {
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("dummyfile.txt");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        logger.info("Exception is", e);
    }
}
```

But the log file do not contain the complete stack trace of the exception. This is not useful from debugging point of view. What could be missing here?

```
{"timestamp":"2021-03-09 18:03:21.443","level":"INFO","thread":"main","logger":"com.test7","message":"Exception is","context":"default","exception":"java.io.FileNotFoundException: linessssss.txt (No such file or directory)\n"}
{"timestamp":"2021-03-09 18:03:21.476","level":"DEBUG","thread":"main","logger":"com.test7","message":"This is a log message","context":"default"}
{"timestamp":"2021-03-09 18:03:21.477","level":"INFO","thread":"main","logger":"com.test7","message":"Exception is","context":"default","exception":"java.io.FileNotFoundException: linessssss.txt (No such file or directory)\n"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source for [`JsonLayout`](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback-contrib/blob/master/json/classic/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/contrib/json/classic/JsonLayout.java) it uses a `ThrowableProxyConverter` to control what ends up in the JSON - so even if you call `setIncludeException` (as [recommended by responses to other similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57602337/logback-how-to-log-entire-msg-using-jsonlayout)) what it does will depend on which converter is selected (didn't spend long enough to see how). You probably want something like the [`RootCauseFirstThrowableProxyConverter`](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/src-html/ch/qos/logback/classic/pattern/RootCauseFirstThrowableProxyConverter.html) or something like it being involved.

Comment: I tried 'HTMLLayout' and 'XMLLayout' for test purposes and they are showing complete stack trace. Only 'JsonLayout' is having this issue.

Comment: That's how it's written - whether that's a bug or not, or by design - there's wasn't enough in the code to make that clear.

Comment: I posted an answer below. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix for this. Added a CustomThrowableProxyConverter and handled the stack trace processing through it.

```
public class CustomThrowableProxyConverter extends ThrowableHandlingConverter {

    public CustomThrowableProxyConverter() {
    }

    @Override
    public String convert(ILoggingEvent event) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        IThrowableProxy itp = event.getThrowableProxy();
        if (itp instanceof ThrowableProxy) {
            ThrowableProxy tp = (ThrowableProxy)itp;
            sb.append(tp.getClassName() + ": " + tp.getMessage());
            for (StackTraceElementProxy element : tp.getStackTraceElementProxyArray()) {
                sb.append("\t\n");
                sb.append(element.getSTEAsString());
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

        return "";
    }
}
```

Then set this into jsonLayout instance.

```
JsonLayout jsonLayout = new JsonLayout();
jsonLayout.setThrowableProxyConverter(new CustomThrowableProxyConverter());
jsonEncoder.setLayout(jsonLayout);
```

Comment: Sometime just the class / line of the exception is enough to give you sufficient clue of what the problem is (although in the case of a rethrow - the root cause is useful too)...  In the logs of one of my applications [that has been in use for 10+ years] the full stack trace tends to not give much extra information ...